# Can't get image to center when I change the browser size

Tags: html, css, gimp

I've created an image using GIMP and have imported it into a website I am creating. For some reason it does not want to center when I resize the browser. In addition, unless I set it's position to absolute, it moves to the middle of the page( I want center, top). I believe it has something to do with the size of the image. It is 1920x1080 and I used this size because of the quality, but I think the background is getting used when I import it. I've tried everything in Gimp to cut out the background. Any suggestion on the code or how to fix this in GIMP it would be great.

```
<div id="logo">
    <img src="DTW Logo\DTW2_Logo_ColombianFlagColorTOPcropped.png" >
</div>

body{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#logo{
margin: -368px 450px 0px 0px;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
```

}

Comment: change the css `position:absolute` to `position:relative`

Comment: see my answer below, hope you are looking for this..

Comment: since other peoples code is not working once you place it in your code, i would suggest you produce a fiddle with your code... As they are technically giving you correct answers

Comment: Is there a way for me to use the image I created in GIMP in fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

Use css **`width`** property in percentage measurement, and **`margin`** set **`auto`** on both side left and right,

#### CSS

```
#logo{
    margin:0px auto;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

View this demo [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pd1oszve/)

---

Set image width on percentage:

```
img{
    width: 15%;
    /*width: 75px */
}
```

View [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pd1oszve/1/)

Comment: Just tried, Doesn't work. I am really starting to think it has to do with the image size...

Comment: You must have to set minimum width of size of image, to prevent scrollbar.

Comment: Close.... same issue I am having with Aru's answer... Now the logo wants to go to the center of the page instead of staying at the top...

Answer (score 1):

hope you are looking like this

**HTML**

```
<div id="logo">
    <img src="http://aoyouth.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/home-icon.png">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img{
    max-width:100%;
}
#logo {
    width: 100px;
    margin:0 auto; 
    position:absolute;
    left:0; right:0; top:50%;  
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kne35gwy/4/)

Comment: change the width of the container (#logo) as per your need, since the image size is too large

Comment: SO CLOSE! The only issue now is that the image isn't at the top of the browser. It slowly moves to the center... Hope this is a clear enough explanation.

Comment: sorry I cant get you properly, do you want the image to be placed in the middle of the page (left, top - center)??

Comment: Center, at the top. Right now it is literally in the center of the browser. I want both the top and center....

Comment: Just saw your edit.... Still not quite working in my code. I really appreciate all the help. Went to you fiddle and when I deleted the top 50% it works on that website, but not on my code...